# Interpretation of "Thou art more lovely and more temperate"

Tags: literature, shakespeare

In sonnet 18, line two

> Thou art more lovely and more temperate

What does the word temperate imply? I googled it up and found that it means less extreme., if so then why compare temperateness with Summer, one of extreme weather, it would have been logical to compare it with a season like Autumn or spring ?

Comment: Don't "google it up" (I like it!), look in a proper dictionary :) http://www.thefreedictionary.com/temperate. Your interpretation is not far off. *She is more temperate (pleasant) than a hot summer day.*

Comment: how is hot pleasant ? warm is pleasant but hot?

Comment: Bingo! Exactly!

Comment: Though R&J is set in northern Italy, I don't know if Shakespeare ever went there in person, or simply wrote about it. Certainly most of his audience would not have visited Verona, and would only be familiar with the [seasons in England](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_the_United_Kingdom) ,where summer is, indeed, the most temperate season: it doesn't get too hot (relatively speaking), and on any given day it's much less likely to rain than in any other season. In other words, the summer weather in England is much more moderate and predictable than in any other time of year.

Comment: @DanBron   "...on any given day it's much less likely to rain than in any other season.....the summer weather in England is much more moderate and predictable than in any other time of year.."  Which England do you know??? I'm currently sitting in a very unseasonably warm, dry (for October) UK. True, we had a nice summer, but last year was a washout! :)

Comment: @Dan: the quote is ***not*** from Romeo and Juliet, but one of Shakespeare's sonnets. It has nothing to do with Italy.

Comment: @myanmite, I've spent maybe 14 days total in the England in my life, all of them in London. So Wikipedia's table of average temps and precipitation is the best I've got :)

Comment: Also: [this site](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/sonnets/18detail.html) and [others](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/sonnets/sonnet_18.html)

Comment: Please remember that words had different meanings in Shakespeare's day.

Answer (score 2):

You are more lovely; if I were to compare you to a hot summer day, I would find you milder, more pleasant.

Comment: The modern definition is not necessarily the one that applied in Shakespeare's day.

Answer (score 1):

Shakespeare was writing around 400 years ago, and the meaning of many words has changed significantly in that time. Modern-day definitions will sometimes give a wrong understanding of a phrase, and this is one of those cases.

The meaning of "temperate" at Shakespeare's time was "self-restrained, abstemious, gentle-natured" also "calm, moderate, composed". While it is tempting because of the juxtaposition with "summer's day" to apply the modern usage, where the word is mainly used in relation to temperature and weather, that was not the normal usage of the day. Shakespeare's usage lasted until about a hundred years ago, and can be found in "the temperance movement", a movement against excesses, especially drink.

So the meaning is "you are more moderate and restrained" (which would be considered a good thing). It was also used of weather, and Shakespeare used the 'double meaning' in comparisons a couple of times.

There are sites where you can look up the meaning of words in Shakespeare's time. Here is a link to an example: http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Search.aspx